# Symfony2 minimizing queries when displaying in twig

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

Let's say in my index page I would like to display all of my categories, their subcategories and the number of products each category has.

When I have a lot of objects the query count becomes huge. I already reduced the count by triple by using Querybuilder to fetch all the categories. However, there are stil alot of queries, when I am displaying everything in twig.

```
        {% for category in categories %}
            {% if app.request.getLocale() == 'en' %}
                <li class="subMenu" style="cursor:pointer;"><a> {{ category.name }}</a>
                    <ul>
                    {% for subcategory in category.children %}
                            <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: subcategory.id, name: subcategory.name}) }}">{{ subcategory.name }} [{{ countSubProducts(subcategory.id)}}]</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: category.id, name: category.name}) }}">{{ "category.show_all" | trans }} [{{ countCatProducts(category.id)}}]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="subMenu" style="cursor:pointer;"><a> {{ category.nameEs }}</a>
                    <ul>
                        {% for subcategory in category.children %}
                            <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: subcategory.id, name: subcategory.nameEs}) }}">{{ subcategory.getNameEs }} [{{ countCatProducts(subcategory.id)}}] </a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: category.id, name: category.nameEs}) }}">{{ "category.show_all" | trans }} [{{ countSubProducts(category.id)}}]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I am doing allot of for loops, because I dont know any other way to display each category/subategory.

These loops are making allot of queries... How can I reduce all this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can do something like this :*

**Use of [twig attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)**

```
{%  set myname = "nameEs" %}
{% if app.request.getLocale() == 'en' %}
    {%  set myname = "name" %}
{% endif %}

{% for category in categories %}
        <li class="subMenu" style="cursor:pointer;"><a> {{ attribute(category, myname) }}</a>
            <ul>
                {% for subcategory in category.children %}
                    <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: subcategory.id, name: attribute(subcategory, myname)}) }}">{{ attribute(subcategory, myname) }} [{{ countSubProducts(subcategory.id)}}]</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                <li><a href="{{ path('products_in_categories', {id: category.id, name: attribute(category, myname)}) }}">{{ "category.show_all" | trans }} [{{ countCatProducts(category.id)}}]</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```